# How to add custom JS in admin Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, requirejs

I'm trying to add a custom js file in magento 2 in the admin but all I can see are sample on how to add in the frontend. I found some that shows how to add in admin but none works. Below are my code that I copied from some sources

```
//app/code/COMPANY/PRODUCT/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "generateMenu": "TCM_HeaderMenu/js/generateMenu"
        }
    }
}
```

and in the file located in `app/code/COMPANY/PRODUCT/view/adminhtml/web/js/generateMenu.js`

```
  /**
   * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
  require([
      'jquery',
      'logger'

  ],  function($, logger) {
      'use strict';
      logger.log('inchoo.js is loaded!!');

      //creating jquery widget
      $.widget('generateMenu.js', {
          _create: function() {

              this.element.on('click', function(e){
                  logger.log("You click on element: " + e.target);
              });
          }

      });

    return $.generateMenu.js;
  });
```

But it seems that this is not being called when I refresh the page.

Note: I'm trying to load the custom js in Catalog->category page in the admin panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

> app/code/Company/Product/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {

    deps: [
        "Company_Product/js/generateMenu"
    ]

};
```

> app/code/Company/Product/view/adminhtml/web/js/generateMenu.js

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
  "use strict";
 //Your code here
});
```

> clean cache
>
> clean var/view_preprocessed **content**
>
> clean pub/static **content**
>
> deploy the static **content** : php bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: You're the star thanks a lot you saved me been looking for this answer for hours now

Answer (score 0):

please try with below code :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            generateMenu:'TCM_HeaderMenu::js/generateMenu'
        }
    }
};
```

**i hope its work for you**